# No Spring Tests are being run

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, surefire

I've got the following pom.xml surefire config:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <printSummary>true</printSummary>
        <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>

        <includes>
            <include>**/test/resources/META-INF/spring/test-database.properties</include> 
            <include>**/src/test/java/*.java</include>
        </includes>

        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*_Roo_*</exclude>
            <exclude>**/database-*.properties</exclude>
        </excludes>

    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And the following applicationContext.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

<!-- FOR UNIT TESTING ONLY -->

    <!--
        This will automatically locate any and all property files you have
        within your classpath, provided they fall under the META-INF/spring
        directory. The located property files are parsed and their values can
        then be used within application context files in the form of
        ${propertyKey}.
    -->

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/test-database.properties"/>

    <bean id="externalProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
       <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound"><value>true</value></property>
       <property name="locations">
          <list>
            <value>classpath*:META-INF/conf/configuration.properties</value>
          </list>
       </property>
    </bean>

    <!--
        Turn on AspectJ @Configurable support. As a result, any time you
        instantiate an object, Spring will attempt to perform dependency
        injection on that object. This occurs for instantiation via the "new"
        keyword, as well as via reflection. This is possible because AspectJ
        is used to "weave" Roo-based applications at compile time. In effect
        this feature allows dependency injection of any object at all in your
        system, which is a very useful feature (without @Configurable you'd
        only be able to dependency inject objects acquired from Spring or
        subsequently presented to a specific Spring dependency injection
        method). Roo applications use this useful feature in a number of
        areas, such as @PersistenceContext injection into entities.
    -->
    <context:spring-configured/>
    <!--
        This declaration will cause Spring to locate every @Component,
        @Repository and @Service in your application. In practical terms this
        allows you to write a POJO and then simply annotate the new POJO as an
        @Service and Spring will automatically detect, instantiate and
        dependency inject your service at startup time. Importantly, you can
        then also have your new service injected into any other class that
        requires it simply by declaring a field for your service inside the
        relying class and Spring will inject it. Note that two exclude filters
        are declared. The first ensures that Spring doesn't spend time
        introspecting Roo-specific ITD aspects. The second ensures Roo doesn't
        instantiate your @Controller classes, as these should be instantiated
        by a web tier application context. Refer to web.xml for more details
        about the web tier application context setup services.

        Furthermore, this turns on @Autowired, @PostConstruct etc support. These 
        annotations allow you to use common Spring and Java Enterprise Edition 
        annotations in your classes without needing to do any special configuration. 
        The most commonly used annotation is @Autowired, which instructs Spring to
        dependency inject an object into your class.
    -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mms.pone.portal">
        <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex"/>
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <!--<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/> 
        <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="25" />
    </bean> -->

     <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/test-persistence.xml" />
    </bean>    
</beans>
```

Everything seems right, but when I run mvn clean install or mvn test, the file compiles, shows no errors and shows the summary Tests Run: 0.

Any help would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: The `includes/excludes` tags should describe a pattern for files that has tests classes. The `.properties` files should **not** be there. Look here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Comment: Check that the `<includes>` is actually including your tests. Also that your `<excludes>` is not excluding them.

Comment: I read that. The problem I'm getting is that WITHOUT including the test-database.properties, when running mvn clean install, it will use the database.properties file, configured for MySql instead of Hypersonic (Using hypersonic for tests, mysql for production)

Comment: Forgive the noob question, any indication on how exactly I make sure of that?

Comment: there is no need for you to include the line <include>**/src/test/java/*.java</include>, maven will automatically run the test files if they are present in src/test/java

Comment: Right now it behaves the same with or without it, it was just a wild shot (hoping for an on/off fix)...

Comment: Are you sure that you have all your test classes in `src/test/java` and **not** in `src/main/java`?

Comment: By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:

"**/Test*.java" filenames that start with "Test".
"**/*Test.java" filenames that end with "Test".
"**/*TestCase.java" filenames that end with "TestCase".

Comment: @TheCat That's what I was linking to in my comment ;-)

Comment: Try removing the ** off the front so, `<include>/src/test/java/*.java</include>`

Comment: Identical behaviour, sadly...

Comment: The thing is that with your include tag you are actually saying that you want to run all test classes that are in the `src/test/java/` folder. Not in any subfolders! So if you have test classes in say `src/test/java/my/package/` they will effectively be excluded.

Comment: Okay I dont know, here is summary of the patterns you can use with some examples. Maybe it will help http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns

Comment: @maba I'm new to Spring (obviously), but I really don't understand why it behaves the same WITH and WITHOUT that include *.java....no idea what the hell I'm doing wrong

Comment: Yes I know the Ant patterns :-) But in your case you'd have to say `<include>**/src/test/java/**/*.java</include>`. Or even `<include>src/test/java/**/*.java</include>` since the first `**` are obsolete.

Comment: I'd say skip those `includes/excludes` parts in the surefire plugin. Then make sure that your test classes ends or starts with `Test`. After that you can tell us what your *real* problem is.

Comment: If you are using spring-roo in your project then this exclude `<exclude>**/*_Roo_*</exclude>` should be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found this link, discovered the issue to be double property declarations, both in my persistence.xml as well as in my applicationContext.xml. Once those were cleaned out and had my files looking:

applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="false"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="false"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="false"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="1" />

        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
    </bean>
```

persistence.xml

```
  <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
    </properties>
```

Everything ran just fine.